# Can I use a SVG object in place of an img file on web page?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a web page with a series of rows and columns, each column has an icon or image file. When an image is touched it will change color. I am currently doing this with JQuery and swapping out a new image with the new color.

I was thinking that I could do the same with SVG objects and then just change the style class for the object.
The problem that I have been having is getting my SVG object to actually sit in the table cells.
My SVG code:

```
<svg>
 <path d="m 524.9 304 c 53.3 0 96.1 12.7 96.1 28.6 l 0 78 c 0 15.8 -42.9 28.6 -96.1 28.6 -53.3 0 -96.1 -12.7 -96.1 -28.6 l 0 -78 c 0 -15.8 42.9 -28.6 96.1 -28.6 z" id="seat" />
 </svg>
```

This draws the object in the middle of my page even though I put this inside a `<td></td>`.

Is there a way to center an path like there is a shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough to tell out of context, but just from the code you have there it seems like you ought to assign a size to the svg element.

Sizing with svg is a little odd, since it's meant to be scalable. I would recommend adding three extra attributes to your `<svg>` tag:

`width` and `height` which are the size at which the svg element is displayed on the page. These are pretty straightforward and you can adjust them with your css.

`viewBox` is the really important one. It defines the boundaries of your image, and gives you a lot of control over relative sizing. Its value should be a string with 4 space-separated values: `x y w h` where `x` and `y` represent the coordinates of the top-left corner of the part of the image that will be visible, and `w` and `h` are the width and height of the visible portion of the image. These coordinates are relative within your drawing and will be scaled to the display size defined by `width` and `height`.

If the coordinates of your path or other svg elements lie outside of the viewBox they will be effectively cropped away.

I put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7U45/) that should help to illustrate how width, height, and viewBox relate. Hope that helps.

Comment: Here is a fiddle using your SVG to show what you need to do. http://jsfiddle.net/Vy5mh/